# RcppCNPy not usable after Rcpp update

Tags: r, numpy, rcpp

I am trying to use some older code that relies on RcppCNPy, which used to work on my machine. At some point in the past few months I updated Rcpp and now when I try to attach the RcppCNPy library (`library() or require()`) I get the following:

```
*** caught segfault ***
address 0x0, cause 'memory not mapped'
Segmentation fault: 11
```

and then R crashes. I have tried updating both packages (from source and CRAN for Rcpp) and no luck. Any ideas how I could figure out what is going on?

Here are some details that may help:

```
R> sessionInfo()

R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recompilation ought to work. Check that you do not have an old version in your `.libPath()`.

CRAN does checks on packages on would alert the respective maintainer (me, in this case) if RcppCNPy were broken on the Mac. See

- [Page with all checks](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/checks/check_results_RcppCNPy.html)
- [OS X Mavericks results](http://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-release-osx-x86_64-mavericks/RcppCNPy-00check.html)

OS X Mavericks shows a 'Note' but that is simply due to vignette processing and a latex style file.

Comment: Ok, manually deleting the packages from libPath and then reinstalling worked. Strange...

Comment: That's weird.  A standard `install.packages()` should have overwritten as well. Oh well -- at least it is working now!